# how to validate object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to validate the object exists with input object in javascript

I have resultant object and should check the property exists in other input objects, if all exists return true else false

```
/* result object */
var result_query= {
  send_country: 'Singapore', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country_name'
  sccy: 'SGD', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country-from'
  receive_country: 'India', // check if exist in obj_cn'popular_to'
  rccy: 'INR' // check if exist in obj_ccy 'currency' by using receive_country 
}
/*if all exists return true , if single value doesnot exist return false*/


/* others object */
var paramValue = ["Singapore", "India"];
var obj_cn = [
{
  country_name: "Singapore",
  country_from:["SGD"],
  popular_to: ["India"],
  country_to: ["SGD"],
  country_code: "SG"
},
{
  country_name: "India",
  country_from:["INR"],
  popular_to: ["UnitedStates"],
  country_to: ["USD"],
  country_code: "IN"
}
]
var obj_ccy = [
{
   currency: "SGD",
   country_code: "SG",
   country_name: "Singapore"
}
]
```

Comment: Change the domain and its jargon, can you come up with a simple example? Also show something you tried.

Comment: @sabithpocker thanks for prompty reply, have updated what i have tried using javascript

Comment: What are input objects?

Comment: @MarkBaijens thanks for reply , paramValue, obj_cn, obj_ccy are inputs

Comment: @MarkBaijens  thanks for the answer but still returning true, if result_obj send_country is Singapore and sccy is INR , it should be false, according to input object,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `filter()` function on javscript arrays that contain objects in combination with `indexOf()` for the arrays that contain strings only.

Written the code in a snippet but i recommend to make a function out of it.

```js
//Source data objects
var obj_cn = [{
  country_name: "Singapore",
  country_from:["SGD"],
  popular_to: ["India"],
  country_to: ["SGD"],
  country_code: "SG"
}];

var obj_ccy = [{
   currency: "SGD",
   country_code: "SG",
   country_name: "Singapore"
}];

var result_query = {
  send_country: 'Singapore', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country_name'
  sccy: 'INR', // check if exist in obj_cn 'country-from'
  receive_country: 'India', // check if exist in obj_cn'popular_to'
  rccy: 'INR' // check if exist in obj_ccy 'currency' by using receive_country 
};

//city check
var cityFound = obj_cn.filter(function(cn) {
  return cn.country_name == result_query.send_country;
}).length > 0;

//sccy check
var sccyFound = obj_cn.filter(function(cn) {
  return cn.country_from.indexOf(result_query.sccy) != -1;
}).length > 0;

//country check
var countryFound = obj_cn.filter(function(cn) {
  return cn.popular_to.indexOf(result_query.receive_country) != -1;
}).length > 0;

//ccy check
var ccyFound = obj_cn.filter(function(ccy) {
  return ccy.currency == result_query.rccy;
}).length > 0;

//test results
console.log("City found: " + cityFound);
console.log("Sccy found: " + sccyFound);
console.log("Country found: " + countryFound);
console.log("Ccy found: " + ccyFound);
console.log("All found: " + (cityFound && sccyFound && countryFound && ccyFound));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still returning true, if result_obj send_country is Singapore and sccy is INR , it should be false, according to input object,

Comment: @Senthil I Updated my answer so the `result_query.sccy` is `INR`  and it does result in false.